# Series of Imaginary part of a function

Tags: series-expansion

I want to expand Imaginary part of the below function, knowing that all parameters are real. I did like this:

```
Series[Im[((2 I q xt)/(Dc q - (I ep Cos[t])/(G + eta q^2)) - 
Sqrt[q] \[Sqrt] (q ((2 I xt)/(
       Dc q - (I ep Cos[t])/(G + eta q^2)) + (
       Cos[t] (-3 ep + 2 (G + eta q^2) v + A ep Cos[2 t]))/(
       G + eta q^2))^2 + 
    8 ((ep q Cos[
         t]^2 (-ep + 2 (G + eta q^2) v + A ep Cos[2 t]))/(G + 
         eta q^2)^2 + (
       q xt Cos[t] (-ep + 2 (G + eta q^2) v + A ep Cos[2 t]))/(
       I Dc q (G + eta q^2) + ep Cos[t]) + 
       v (-((ep q)/(G + eta q^2)) - (2 xr)/(
          Dc q - (I ep Cos[t])/(G + eta q^2)) - (
          A ep q Cos[2 t])/(G + eta q^2)) Sin[t]^2)))], {q, 0, 2}]
```

But it can not calculate the imaginary part. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are all the variables real-valued?

Comment: Yes, they are @J.M.

Comment: Try evaluating `ComplexExpand[Im[(* stuff *)], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]` to get a real-valued expression that you can feed into `Series[]`.

Comment: In addition to the recommendation by @JM, you will get simpler results if you can add assumptions (constraints) on any of the variables, e.g., are any positive or at least nonnegative? Is `t` constrained to say the interval `{0, Pi/2}`?

Comment: t is in the interval {0, Pi}. v and G are positive. @BobHanlon

Comment: What does TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im} mean? @J.M.

Comment: It ensures any complex expressions that might remain untouched be explicitly cast in terms of `Re[]` and `Im[]`. Please read the documentation for `ComplexExpand[]` for further elaboration.